# Highlight Two Tables At The Same Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 Tables side by side in my web page. 1st one is holding student's schdule, and 2nd one holds teacher's schdule. And In my css file i have these codes:

```
table {
     overflow: hidden;
}
 body:not(.nohover) tbody tr:hover {
     background-color: #ffa;
}
 td:hover::after, thead th:not(:empty):hover::after, td:focus::after, thead th:not(:empty):focus::after {
     content: '';
     height: 10000px;
     left: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: -5000px;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: -1;
}
 td:hover::after, th:hover::after {
     background-color: #ffa;
}
 td:focus::after, th:focus::after {
     background-color: lightblue;
}
```

These css codes highlights the row and the column of the tables. As i say before i have 2 tables and make the hover both tables at the same time. I mean for example when mouse is over row:1 col:3 of the first table, i want to highlight row:1 and col:3 of both 1st table and 2nd table at the same time.

Comment: You can't do it with css alone. Will need to toggle a class using javascript. Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) and [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/), you can determine which row is hovered and highlight the corresponding one in the other table.

You cannot "link" different elements like that using only CSS. So here is a short example.

```js
var hoveredRow;
var otherTableRows;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".student tbody tr, .teacher tbody tr").hover(
    function(){
      
      // Determine which table is "the other"
      if( $(this).closest(".student").length>0 ){
        otherTableRows = $(".teacher tbody tr");
      }else{
        otherTableRows = $(".student tbody tr");
      }
      
      // Get the hovered row index
      hoveredRow = $(this).index();
      
      // Highlight on moueenter
      $(this).css({"background-color": "#ffa"});
      otherTableRows.eq(hoveredRow).css({"background-color": "#ffa"});
    },
    function(){
      // Unhighlight on mouseout
      $(this).css({"background-color": "initial"});
      otherTableRows.eq(hoveredRow).css({"background-color": "initial"});
    }
  );
});
```

```css
table {
  overflow: hidden;
  float:left;
  margin:0 3em;
}
td{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="student">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col 1
      </th>
      <th>col 2
      </th>
      <th>col 3
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1
      </td>
      <td>data 2
      </td>
      <td>data 3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1
      </td>
      <td>data 2
      </td>
      <td>data 3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1
      </td>
      <td>data 2
      </td>
      <td>data 3
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="teacher">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col 1
      </th>
      <th>col 2
      </th>
      <th>col 3
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1
      </td>
      <td>data 2
      </td>
      <td>data 3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1
      </td>
      <td>data 2
      </td>
      <td>data 3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1
      </td>
      <td>data 2
      </td>
      <td>data 3
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Highlighting hovered row AND column**

```js
var hoveredRow;
var hoveredRowIndex;
var hoveredCellIndex;
var otherTableRows;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".student tbody td, .teacher tbody td").hover(
    function(){
      
      // Determine which table is "the other"
      if( $(this).closest(".student").length>0 ){
        otherTableRows = $(".teacher tbody tr");
      }else{
        otherTableRows = $(".student tbody tr");
      }
      
      // Get the hovered row index
      hoveredRow = $(this).parent("tr");
      hoveredRowIndex = hoveredRow.index();
      
      // Get the hovered cell index
      hoveredCellIndex = $(this).index();
                     
      
      // Highlight on moueenter
      hoveredRow.css({"background-color": "#ffa"});
      hoveredRow.closest("table").find("tr").each(function(){
        $(this).find("td").eq(hoveredCellIndex).css({"background-color": "#ffa"});
      });
      
      otherTableRows.eq(hoveredRowIndex).css({"background-color": "#ffa"});
      otherTableRows.each(function(){
        $(this).find("td").eq(hoveredCellIndex).css({"background-color": "#ffa"});
      })
    },
    function(){
      // Unhighlight on mouseout
      hoveredRow.css({"background-color": "initial"});
      hoveredRow.closest("table").find("tr").each(function(){
        $(this).find("td").eq(hoveredCellIndex).css({"background-color": "initial"});
      });
      
      otherTableRows.eq(hoveredRowIndex).css({"background-color": "initial"});
      otherTableRows.each(function(){
        $(this).find("td").eq(hoveredCellIndex).css({"background-color": "initial"});
      })
    }
  );
});
```

```css
table {
  overflow: hidden;
  float:left;
  margin:0 3em;
}
td{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="student">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col 1
      </th>
      <th>col 2
      </th>
      <th>col 3
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1
      </td>
      <td>data 2
      </td>
      <td>data 3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1
      </td>
      <td>data 2
      </td>
      <td>data 3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1
      </td>
      <td>data 2
      </td>
      <td>data 3
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="teacher">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col 1
      </th>
      <th>col 2
      </th>
      <th>col 3
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1
      </td>
      <td>data 2
      </td>
      <td>data 3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1
      </td>
      <td>data 2
      </td>
      <td>data 3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data 1
      </td>
      <td>data 2
      </td>
      <td>data 3
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can i also highlight the columns that are hovered, not only rows?

Comment: You will have to base the script on the hovered `td`, then find the parent `tr` to highlight it. And also highlight the `td` of all rows using the index... The logic is the same, but there is just a little more deductions to do.